# Symfony, nginx and "File not found."

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have problem with nginx instance on OVH serwer.

When I go to my page i have error "File not found.".

/etc/nginx/sites-available/defaul
from official Symfony configuration:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

```
server {
    server_name 51.255.193.179;
    root /root/www/harccal/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

error_log:

```
2016/01/13 23:57:04 [crit] 9372#0: *9 stat() "/root/www/harccal/web/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 89.70.84.185, server: 51.255.193.179, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "51$
2016/01/13 23:57:04 [crit] 9372#0: *9 realpath() "/root/www/harccal/web" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 89.70.84.185, server: 51.255.193.179, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: $
2016/01/13 23:57:04 [error] 9372#0: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 89.70.84.185, server: 51.255.193.179, request: "$
```

prem:

```
:~/www/harccal# ls -al
total 1332
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root    4096 sty 13 22:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 sty 13 21:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    4096 sty 13 22:24 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 sty 13 22:13 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2669 sty 13 21:51 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   67193 sty 13 22:13 composer.lock
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1248055 sty 13 22:02 composer.phar
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root    4096 sty 13 21:51 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      80 sty 13 21:51 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      85 sty 13 21:51 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 sty 13 21:51 src
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4096 sty 13 22:24 vendor
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root    4096 sty 13 22:03 web
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I dont have more logs. or I dont know when find it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/root` directory by default does not have read permissions by `other` users, which is pretty much reasonable. And most likely it has `700` permissions.

What happens next - your webserver user `www-data` tries to read files in `/root/www/harccal/web`. But the first directory in the chain (`/root`) is not readable by it. So it terminates with `9 stat() "/root/www/harccal/web/" failed (13: Permission denied)`

For a file to be readable - every parent directory must be traversable as well.

Solution: you better move your application to another directory, that is accessible by a webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After 3 hours of debugging, changing permissions back and forth, restarting everything I noticed that my local app.php was not uploaded to the remote host.

So if you run into the same error, *one* of several solutions can be to ensure that all your local files are correctly uploaded to your virtual host.